# How to add a condition to check if the subject line does not contain certain text and the recipient is outside of the organization?

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code forces a prompt for confirmation before an email is sent.

I would like to add a condition where the prompt only appears if the subject line does not contain the word "encrypt" and the recipient is outside of the organization.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim xPrompt As String
Dim xOkOrCancel As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xPrompt = "Do you want to continue sending the email?"
xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbOKCancel)
If xOkOrCancel <> vbOK Then
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use InStr() function in vba for outlook such that:

```
With Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 'change this
    If Not InStr(.Subject, "PO") AND right(.senderemailaddres,7) = "@123.com" Then 'do something
End With
```